# What is the probability of drawing more than $15$ red marbles?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Question: An urn contains $2$ white marbles and $8$ red marbles. A marble is drawn $20$ times in succession with replacement. What is the probability of drawing more than $15$ red marbles?

I had a problem just like this a while back (posted on here) but the marbles was drawn randomly in succession though. So I am stuck on this because it is not random. Also I was told to use a calculator on this so my answer can be accurate without mistakes. Thing is, I need help using the binomial distribution on my calculator (TI-$84$ plus silver edition). Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no need to be confused. *In succession* just means *one by one* or *one after another*, and we are told it's with replacement. They are still drawn randomly. Does that clarify your confusion?

To find the binomial coefficient ${_nC_r} = \binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ on the TIs, you usually go to an option called "PRB" and it should be something like ${_nC_r}$ or $C(n,r)$.

[Here](http://www.dummies.com/education/graphing-calculators/how-to-use-the-binomial-theorem-on-the-ti-84-plus/) is one guide I found on the TI-84 PLUS.

Comment: my $n$=$20$ and $r$=$16$?

Comment: Yes, except that will just give you the coefficient for $P(X = 16)$. You still need to add up 17 through 20

Comment: too add it up, it should be $\frac{16}{20}$ for $X$=$16$? and so forth

Comment: Not completely. Maybe you remember from you "previous question" but  $P(X = 16) = \binom{20}{16} (8/10)^{16}(2/10)^{20-16}$, from the binomial distribution.

Comment: Okay. I just looked at the old post again. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The number of red marbles, call it $X$, follows a $\text{Binomial}(20, 8/10)$ distribution. (Why?)

The probability you seek can be computed as
$$P(X > 15) = P(X=16) + P(X=17) + P(X=18) + P(X=19)+P(X=20).$$
Use the definition of the binomial distribution to compute each term on the right-hand side.